# Theano ~ most efficient way to flatten then build back a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, theano

I am trying to compute the hessian on a neural network using theano.

However, I cannot compute the hessian on my loss function with respect to a weight matrix `W`. The hessian needs to be computed with respect to a vector `v`.

So, a way around this is to flatten the weight matrix into a vector, then compute the hessian, etc.

Once I am done updating my weight matrix in flattened form, I need to rebuild my weight matrix with the original dimensions, say `m x n`

What is the most efficient way to do this using theano syntax?

Comment: You want "theano syntax", but what about using numpy to [flatten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.flatten.html) it and [reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to build it back up?

Comment: even you flatten the matrix, let me know if you can compute the hessian wrt the long flat vector efficiently. I am computing the hessian of a 20k length vector and theano takes forever

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your looking for "reshape", like @Pushkin mentioned.

You can use reshape in Theano just like Numpy, but it's with their custom tensor object.

1. Save weight matrix shape to variable.
2. Flatten and compute.
3. Call reshape with the previously saved shape variable.

["Theano - Reshape Tensor"](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.reshape)

Comment: thanks, however there are two ways for a `m*n` dimensional vector to be converted into a `m x n` matrix. E.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` can become `[ [1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5] ]` (if we layer the data row by row) or `[ [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6] ]` (if we layer the data column by column), so when I take the vector and convert it back to a matrix, would it take the same form as the original matrix?

Comment: `numpy.reshape()` will return the first one.

Comment: If you want it to work the other way, just transpose.